# What is Objective coefficient for new variable

Tags: gurobi

In order to create new GRBVar, I need to provide Objective coefficient for [new variable](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.5/refman/java_grbmodel_addvar.html):

```
GRBVar var = model.addVar (double lowerBound,
        double upperBound,
        double obj, // objective coefficient
        char type,
        String name);
```

According to [this example](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.5/examples/mip1_java.html), the value can be set to 0. So I wonder what objective coefficient is.

Answer (score 8):

Objective coefficient is the coefficient of the variable in your objective function. In the example you have given :

```
 maximize    x +   y + 2 z
 subject to  x + 2 y + 3 z <= 4
             x +   y       >= 1
 x, y, z binary
```

your objective function is maximize    x +   y + 2 z

so Objective coefficients are
for x: 1
for y: 1
 and for z: 2

While creating variables you can give coefficients **arbitrary** ( here they are as you said 0.0 )

```
 // Create variables

  GRBVar x = model.addVar(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, GRB.BINARY, "x");
  GRBVar y = model.addVar(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, GRB.BINARY, "y");
  GRBVar z = model.addVar(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, GRB.BINARY, "z");
```

But later you should set to the actual objective coefficients:

```
  // Set objective: maximize x + y + 2 z

  GRBLinExpr expr = new GRBLinExpr();
  expr.addTerm(1.0, x); 
  expr.addTerm(1.0, y); 
  expr.addTerm(2.0, z);
  model.setObjective(expr, GRB.MAXIMIZE);
```

Comment: then what is the use of using `Objective Coefficients` while creating variables. Could you please elaborate your answer?.

Comment: You can mix and match the two methods to create an objective. If you use the objectve coefficients it will create a linear objective and it will get minimized, unless you specify `model.ModelSense = GRB.MAXIMIZE` which will maximize this linear combination. If you use `setObjective` it will override the former.